# R Shiny: Add a reactive event to only render plots after query has returned data

Tags: r, shiny, google-bigquery

I would like to only render plots after data has been returned from my query.  I have a BQ query that only runs when the input button "do_sql" has been pushed, however I am not sure if my syntax is correct as I get errors for my plots.

"Error: object of type 'environment' is not subsettable" for plots "Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" for the datatable.

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(bigQueryR)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {


data6 <- observeEvent(input$do_sql, {
bqr_auth(token = NULL, new_user = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)

projectId <- "projectId"
datasetId <- "publicdata"
query <- "SELECT *
FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
LIMIT 100"

bqr_query(projectId, datasetId, query, maxResults =2000)

})
data <- eventReactive(input$do_sql, {
temp <- data6


if (input$year != "All"){
  temp <- temp[temp$year == input$year,]
}
if (input$month != "All"){
  temp <- temp[temp$month == input$month,]
}
if (input$partner_name != "All"){
  temp <- temp[temp$partner_name == input$partner_name,]
}
if (input$cube_title != "All"){
  temp <- temp[temp$cube_title == input$cube_title,]
}
 return(temp)

})

#plots
output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
temp <- data()


})

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

temp <- data()
ggplot(data=subset(temp,cube_title=="Leads"), aes(x=month,y=f0_)) + geom_bar(fill="blue", stat = "identity") + ylab("Leads") + ggtitle("Leads")
}) 
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
temp <- data()
  ggplot(data=subset(temp,cube_title=="Clickthroughs"), aes(x=month,y=f0_)) + geom_bar(fill="green", stat = "identity") + ylab("Clickthroughs") + ggtitle("Builder Clickthroughs")
})
})
```

**ui.r**

```
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
skin = "blue",
dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
dashboardSidebar(
 ( 
      selectInput("year", 
                  "Year:", 
                  c("All", 
                   unique(as.character(data6$year))))
  ),
  ( 
      selectInput("month", 
                  "Month:", 
                  c("All", 
                    unique(as.character(data6$month))))
  ),
  (
      selectInput("partner_name", 
                  "Partner:", 
                  c("All", 
                    unique(as.character(data6$partner_name))))
  ),

   (
      selectInput("cube_title", 
                  "cube_title:", 
                  c("All", 
                    unique(as.character(data6$cube_title))))
        ),


 actionButton("do_sql", "Go!")

)

,

dashboardBody(


 tabsetPanel(id = "tabSelected",
    tabPanel("Charts", plotOutput("plot1"), 
            box(plotOutput("plot2"))),
            tabPanel("DataTable", DT::dataTableOutput("table1"),
                     downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
)

           )
        )
```

Comment: Try passing `if (is.null(data())) return(NULL)` to the beginning of `output$table1`, `output$plot1`, and `output$plot2`. I get the feeling this is an issue of those outputs trying to render when `data()` hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Didn't seem to work.  I'm still getting the same errors right when pushing the input button (which is technically before the data is returned).  Here's my syntax:

    output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(data())) return(NULL)
    temp <- data()

Comment: Maybe you need to add `()` to `data6` in your assignment to `temp` in `data`? Also, are you sure the results from `bqr_query` are being sent to `data6`? Lastly, is there any reason you can't combine `data` and `data6` so that only one event triggers on `input$do_sql` given that it seems `data6` is just used to be passed to `data`?

Comment: I also think the error comes because of the reason pointed out by @brittenb . Did you use `if (is.null(data())) return(NULL)` for `output$plot1` and `output$plot2` also.

Comment: add a dataset so we can test your code

Comment: I did add `(is.null(data())) return(NULL)` to all of the plots and the table.

When adding `()` to `data` and replacing `data6` with `data` I get a "ERROR: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".  It looks like the filter calls in ui.r don't know what to do if the data is not rendered prior to the filter choices rendering.  I also tried replacing the filter choices with a hard coded list and ended up with the plots and table rendering before data returns.

Comment: Here is a dataset:

    `year <- c('2014','2015','2015','2013','2014') 
    month <- c('Jan','Feb','Feb','Dec','Oct') 
    partner_name <- c('1','2','3','1','3') 
    cube_title <- c('leads','calls','calls','leads','leads') 
    data <- cbind(year,month,partner_name,cube_title)`

Comment: in your code where is f0_ coming from? I ran your app, it opens up but I get "object 'f0_' not found" warning!

Comment: f0_ is a title Bigquery gives to an unnamed column.  If you are running the the query and are not assigning a valid dataset and table, you might get that warning.  I've never seen that particular warning though.  Did you make any changes to my original app?  If so, can you reply?